# Scale vertex Coordinates, but keep alpha channel value the same? GLSL

Tags: opengl, glsl, shader, fragment-shader, vertex-shader

There are two textures that I have to display and they overlap. one of the textures have alpha channel, so it is possible to blend it. However, since the texture coordinates are clumped together, I decided to scale them. `gl_TexCoord[0] = gl_MultiTexCoord0*2.0;`
This does not quite work, because, it sclaes the alpha channel as well. How do I scale the texture coordinates, but keep the alpha channel value the same?

Below are the GLSL shaders.

vertex shader:

```
void main() 
{                
    gl_TexCoord[0] = gl_MultiTexCoord0*2.0;        //this is where I scale the texture
    gl_Position = gl_ModelViewProjectionMatrix * gl_Vertex;
}
```

fragment shader:

```
uniform sampler2D textureSample_0;
uniform sampler2D textureSample_1;

void main() 
{
    vec4 grass=texture2D(textureSample_1, gl_TexCoord[0].st);
    vec4 sand = texture2D(textureSample_0, gl_TexCoord[0].st);
    gl_FragColor = grass*grass.a+sand*(1.0-grass.a);            //alpha channel is also scaled here

}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It's unclear what you mean about scaling the alpha:  the alpha channel in `grass` doesn't come from the texture coordinate, it comes from the texture in `textureSample_1`, just like the colors.  You're scaling all four components of `gl_TexCoord[0]`, but only the `s` and `t` components are actually used for the texture lookup; the other two have no effect.  The fact that `gl_MultiTexCoord0.a` has been multiplied by 2 is irrelevant since it isn't being used for anything.

Comment: @Wyzard, when I run the code without mulyiplying by 2, the grass is in right place, but it looks horrible. However, after multiplying, it gets better, but the place of it is different

Comment: Scaling the texture coordinates by 2 will shrink the apparent size of the texture to be half as high and half as wide.  You'll get four copies of the image in the space that used to be filled by one.  That's all.

Comment: @Wyzard, I need to scale texture coordinates, can you plase show me the right way of doing it?

Comment: You *are* scaling the texture coordinates.  It's unclear what your actual problem is.  Can you add some images to show what's wrong?

Comment: @Wyzard, stackoverflow won't allow me to post pictures. I need to scale the grass and sand

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66179/discussion-between-jack-jackson-and-wyzard).